# Android AccountManager authToken and OAuth

Tags: android, oauth, accountmanager

My task is to write IMAP e-mail client for Gmail. So far I know client should authenticate through OAuth (there's also a [java library for IMAP auth](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/source/browse/trunk/java/com/google/code/samples/xoauth/XoauthAuthenticator.java) by Google). But I'd like to set user free from any password typing.

Android provides a cool 'native' way to gain authToken for google account services via AccountManager. But I wonder how to use authToken and what is it for? Is it only for GAE authentication?

Is there any way to get oauthToken and oauthTokenSecret without browser (via AccountManager)?

Comment: Check out this [talk from Google IO 2011](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/best-practices-for-accessing-google-apis-on-android.html). There's a pretty good user-experience for newer Android devices using the AccountManager described.

Comment: Thanks! But I've already looked through this library and found there's no gmail interaction in Google API. Sad but true, I have to use IMAP. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I'm sure GMail can be accessed via OAuth. I'm using Chrome extensions which can do so.

Comment: OAuth? Certainly. The point was to use Account getAuthToken method and provided authToken for OAuth. But for Gmail it's seems to be impossible.

Comment: I am able to get the auth token using the url oauth2:https://mail.google.com/ but i am not able to figure out how to use this token with javamail.

Comment: Thanks for response. The problem remains. If scope-related problem is solved, than next problem is to figure out how to use this authToken for servers where OAuth tokens are needed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using "`oauth2:https://mail.google.com/`" as the "auth token type" (`authTokenType` parameter) when calling `AccountManager.getAutToken()` ?

According what is said at 46:50 in the [talk you mentioned](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/best-practices-for-accessing-google-apis-on-android.html), it should work.

By the way, [this page](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-google-tasks-api-and-oauth-20-on.html) describes how to get an OAuth2 token for Google Tasks, and it has [a link to a code sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples). It also makes it sounds like it is just a matter of providing the right `authTokenType` parameter.

Comment: It should work and it works! But only for ClientLogin library. Right? When there are many reasons why Android client app should get OAuth tokens, not those which AccountManager provides. And WebView seems to be the only way... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you use the authTokenType provided in the examples, the token given by AccountManager should be an OAuth token. I must admit that I haven't tried it myself yet, but the [last code sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples) seems explicit about this (the token returned by the AccountManager is used with a `oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource` ).

Comment: WoW! Thanks for a comment — I'll try and test token from AccountManager this weekend.

Comment: After getting the token how to set the same in imap while fetching messages or while connecting?

Comment: getting access to google IMAP via AccountManager works fine. see https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus for a project which makes use of this.