# 2 different Google Calendar Sample Codes - Which examples I should apply?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I go through 2 different Google Calendar code samples. After finished reading them, I am getting confused.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate

- They are using oAuth2?
- They are using scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`. Is it because they are using oAuth2?
- They required 2 API keys, `clientId` and `clientSecret`. Is it because they are using oAuth2?
- They are using `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar`.

---

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android/CalendarSample.java?repo=samples

- They are using ClientLogin?
- The scope is `cl`? Is it because they are using ClientLogin?
- They only require 1 simple API access key. Is it because they are using ClientLogin?
- They are using `com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar`. What is the difference with `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar`?

**My target platform is on Android. Should I be using method from 1st example, or 2nd example?**

Comment: If you check the homepage of the second example, the first thing I see is that they claim to use oAuth 2.0, the same as the first.

Comment: @Nanne, I don't see any statement states that 2nd example is using oAuth 2.0. Can you point it out?

Comment: go to the homepage (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) of that project. Read the first line of tekst: `Written by Google, this library is an easy-to-use and efficient Java client library for accessing Google APIs using JSON and **OAuth 2.0.** ` (emph mine)

Comment: Confusing. But @sandis said 2nd example is ClientLogin? Can anyone confirm 2nd example is using oAuth 2.0 or ClientLogin? Thanks.

Comment: No, as far as I can see @sandis said that both oAuth and clientlogin work, there was no mention of what which example does. Anyway, the project itself says it uses oAuth, why doubt that?

Comment: The reason I doubt that is that, they suppose to use `oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` or `Manage your calendars` in AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE. Currently, they are using `cl`.

Comment: Also, the 2nd example is not using any classes from `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2`. Hence, it seems to me they are not using oAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is using Android functionality of [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) which can access stored account information on an Android device. The AccountManager class will do the OAuth in the background, so that the developer doesn't need to. See [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649388/android-accountmanager-authtoken-and-oauth).

Comment: Is there any documentation which talks about this? As I am pretty sure "cl" is the service name used in ClientLogin. https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#clientlogin

Comment: I usually just look at the [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) code sample to see how to use it.